# how to get the value from <h> element in <li> element

Tags: html, web

i have html code and i need to get value from  `<h>` element that is placed in a `<li>` element so i tried the following code

```
<li class="product-price">
    <h3> 7 406,10 dollar    </h3>
 <!-- close price -->
        </li>
                
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("product-price");
  alert(x.item(0).innerHTML);
}
</script>
```

but i am getting [https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCt1X.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as long as h3 is without a class or id so u can get it from it's parent using queryselector,
try the snippet =)

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
var txt = document.querySelector('.product-price :nth-child(1)').innerHTML;

console.log(txt);
});
```

```html
<li class="product-price">
    <h3> 7 406,10 dollar    </h3>
 <!-- close price -->
        </li>
```

Comment: exactly what  i need thank you   @Burham B. Soliman

Answer (score 0):

```
<li >
<h3 class="product-price"> 7 406,10 dollar    </h3>
</li>
```

That should do it.
Although you might need to change the class names

This should also work (if you can't change the html):

```
console.log(x[0].innerHTML);
```

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_htmlcollection.asp

Comment: unfortunately  i can't change the code my job is to get the value only @Shanie

Comment: @anna I added another option

Comment: i have tried it before still getting the same but i got the right answer thanks for your help  @Shanie